# Change IE9 developer tool language to English

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have IE9 installed on Win7 and the system language is not English. I am doing cross-browser testing on this IE9 and want everything in it to be English. After all, English is the working language for developer.

I thought it's easy but it's not at all. First I tried to change IE default language to English by choosing `Tools>Internet Options>General>Language`. I keep only English on the list, then restart the browser.. But nothing happens!

If that's not doable, at least I need the developer tool (especially error messages in console) to be displayed English. Please help.

Comment: Internet Explorer language is fixed, that settings won't affect anything else than address bar (and few other stuffs). You have to (re)install it in the language you prefer (english) and you can't switch between different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the IE language, you need to change the Windows UI language. The options inside Internet Options > General > Language concern what languages IE advertises to websites, but they don't affect IE UI itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this from within the IE. You need to change windows system language to change IEs console language.
In Win10 there is a language settings app. On the left side select language, then you can select the windows language at the top. Relogin or reboot and you are ready to go.